# Trillian Plugins

Tags: c, plugins

I am looking to get started making a plugin for trillian. I have found a sample plugin on there website and some api documentation but I can't seem to find any information on how to build the plugin into a dll... such as compiler.. or any other information. If anyone has worked with making trillian plugins before and could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.